Primary display does not set up ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I hope you can help me out with a problem, it turns out I have two monitors:

Samsung, connected through HDMI port
HP, connected through display port and (displayport to hdmi adapter cause my hp doesn't have a display port, nor my desktop have 2 HDMI ports)

My samsung monitor 1 is to the left and my HP monitor 2 to my right.
I set the Hp monitor 2 to my right as my primary monitor as show in this screenshot

the problem is that the samsung monitor 1 seems to be the primary cause when I:
1.log out

open new firefox windows

copy files and folders to the desktop


always go or open in the samsung monitor 1.
e.g.

most of the time I have my samsung monitor 1 turned off cause I only use it at a certain time of the day and turn it off.
but I have to turn it on just to move the windows or files to my Hp monitor 2, even to log in.
Does it have to do with the HDMI and displayport connections?, I tried to change them and make samsung work with the displayport adapter but it won't work, only the hp worked with this adapter, not really sure if that's the problem I think it's rather a configuration problem.
please help me out!, I don't know how to take system logs in case you need them, so let me know if you need them!!!
thanks in advance guys!
